# How to upload file to Google Cloud Storage without using webform

Tags: google-app-engine, cgi, google-cloud-storage

I was able to setup GCS and upload files successfully based on https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133, from which the following was extracted to show you what it does.

```
field_storage = self.request.POST.get("file", None)

with gcs.open(gcs_file_name, 'w', content_type=content_type,
              options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read'}) as f:
    f.write(field_storage.file.read())
```

Can someone tell me how to **programmatically generate a blob object (such as field_storage) from a string of the full-path file name**(e.g., c:\file1.jpg), rather than using a web form to get the (cgi.FieldStorage) input? This will allow me to batch upload multiple files listed in a text document.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you mean how to post a multipart message, look at this gist:https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9222732

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I'd like to be able to upload files from the local folder to GCS without using web form POST. GAE doesn't seem to allow me to do this. Hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(r'c:\file1.jpg')
data = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I tried it, however, I got [Errno 13] file not accessible. Google AppEngine doesn't seem to allow access to local files on the client side unless through a web form?

Comment: Ah. My apologies, I didn't realize your code was running on App Engine. App Engine apps don't have access to a local filesystem, so you won't be able to read or write arbitrary files (just read files you upload with your app). Could you describe what you're trying to do at a higher level? Where are the files you're trying to upload?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear about that. I'm trying to allow users to upload their contact list including friends' name, phone number and photo (the full path image file name) populated in a text file, to avoid having to upload one contact at a time. And of course, I want the image file to be uploaded instead of the file name string.  Thank you!